# How to fix Laravel Error 404 in acceptance environment?

Tags: laravel, apache, httpd.conf

I try to install my Laravel application in a new environment `acceptance`,

After `composer install` (no errors)

when I check the url it's redirected to `/login` which is normal

The problem: it returns 404 error and this error is coming from the server not from Laravel because I customized 404 error in my application

[image]

it seems like the server does accept only `/` path :

also when I change the router :

from

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    if (Auth::check()) return redirect('/myprofile');
    return redirect('/login');
});
```

To this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return 'hello world'
});
```

it works and I can see `hello world`

the route `/login` exists when I route:list

Comment: Seems to be redirection issue, Please check if mod-rewrite module is enabled for apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if Apache's mod_rewrite module is enabled, If it's not enabled aleady please run below commands to enable it or else jump to second part of the answer

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Also add below config block in your virtual host configuration to enable laravels .htaccess rules

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Change /var/www/ path accordingly